# Whats the proper BLOB type for HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, blob

Just like in the topic - I am not able to find the available data types for blobs anywhere. I am trying to create a BLOB of `.html` file. What type should I use?

Comment: What type of BLOB are you talking about? JavaScript has them. SQL has them (with different databases possibly having variations of them). What do you want to do with the BLOB when you have it? You need to provide more context for your question. (Also I suspect you want to check the spelling on your tags).

Answer (score -1):

BLOB are Binary Large Objects. They are used to save large data in database although BLOB is not supported for all of them. But BLOB is a data type itself, so I think you don't have to find another data type for your purpose.